# socket.io net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR forever

Tags: node.js, socket.io, forever

I am using Node.js, Socket.io with forever module.

The script runs well for days, till randomly begins to throw this error:

```
net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

This is the code I use:

```
var https = require('https'),fs = require('fs');        

var options = {
    key:    fs.readFileSync('cert/www.domain.com.key'),
    cert:   fs.readFileSync('cert/www.domain.com.crt')
};
var app = https.createServer(options);
io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
app.listen(8080, "0.0.0.0");
```

How can I avoid this?.

Comment: it's because you're using `https` if that's a hard requirement try whitelisting the server https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#Simple_example